# Clear recent tasks in android P

Tags: java, android, android-9.0-pie

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    public static void clearRecentApps() {
        ActivityManager mActivityManager;
        Method mRemoveTask;
        try {
            Class<?> ActivityThread = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityThread");
            Method method = ActivityThread.getMethod("currentActivityThread");
            Object currentActivityThread = method.invoke(ActivityThread);
            Method method2 = currentActivityThread.getClass().getMethod("getApplication");
            Context contextInstance = (Context) method2.invoke(currentActivityThread);
            Class<?> activityManagerClass = Class.forName("android.app.ActivityManager");
            mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) contextInstance.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            print("Clear all recent tasks!!");
            mRemoveTask = activityManagerClass.getMethod("removeTask", int.class);
            mRemoveTask.setAccessible(true);
            List<ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo> recents =
                    mActivityManager.getRecentTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE, ActivityManager.RECENT_IGNORE_UNAVAILABLE);
            for (ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo recent: recents) {
                ComponentName cn = recent.baseActivity;
                if (cn == null) continue;
                String pkg = cn.getPackageName();
                if (pkg.contains("launcher")) continue;
                print("--> Clear activity \"%s\"", pkg);
                mRemoveTask.invoke(mActivityManager, recent.persistentId);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The method worked before android P, but android P not, I viewed source code of android P, class activitymanager have removed API "removeTask",so i want to know what's the other alternative? i tried  "List appTasks = mActivityManager.getAppTasks();"

Comment: `ActivityManager.getService().removeTask(taskId);`